# Why is netbeans getting stuck running my simple program?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using netbeans 6.8:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Build 200912041610)
Java: 1.6.0_18; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 16.0-b13
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
Userdir: C:\Users\Andre\.netbeans\6.8
```

I have copied a program out of a book I am using to do C++ self study. Here is the code:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Andre
 *
 * Created on December 5, 2011, 2:06 PM
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//using namespace std;

using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main() {

    // ask for the persons name
    std::string name;
    cin >> name;

    // build the message that we intend to write
    const string greeting = "Hello, " + name + "!";

    // the number of blanks surrounding the greeting
    const int pad = 1;

    // the number of rows and columns to write
    const int rows = pad * 2 + 3;
    const string::size_type cols = greeting.size() + pad * 2 + 2;

    // write a blank line to separate the output from the input
    cout << endl;

    // write rows "rows of output"
    // invariant: we have written r rows so far
    for (int r = 0; r != rows; ++r) {
        string::size_type c = 0;

        // invariant: we have written c characters so far in the current row
        while (c != cols) {
            // is it time to write the greeting?
            if (r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) {
                cout << greeting.size();
            } else {
                // are we on the border?
                if (r == 0 || r == rows - 1 || c == 0 || c == cols - 1) {
                    cout << "*";
                } else {
                    cout << " ";
                    ++c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the build results:

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/acccpp20.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 569ms)

/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/acccpp20.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/acccpp20 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o  
make[2]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/d/Users/Andre/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AccCpp20'
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

When I run the program I get a message in the output area of netbeans that says `"Process is starting in external window..."` and a terminal window that pops up with `"C:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe` with just a blank screen and blinking cursor.

When I did a simple program just printing out `"Hi!"` it works fine. What is going on with this??

Also, how do I do a code block posting a question?? The tutorial said something about 4 spaces...

Comment: Its waiting for you to type in your name and press enter..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you get a blank screen with a cursor if your first statement is a Cin? What happens if you enter something?

Comment: Talk about feeling like an idiot. :) Clearly in the book it has the "Please enter your name" line! I was also missing another line, way down in the code. I am currently have a new problem where after I type my name and hit enter, it just continually prints "*"'s over and over again. Must have another error somewhere. It was doing this before I added the two missing lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its waiting for you to type in your name and press enter.. at which point it should continue running. If you want it to ask you to do this you need to do something like:

```
int main() {

    // ask for the persons name
    cout << "Please enter your name" << endl;

    std::string name;
    cin >> name;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `cin>>` the program expects that the user writes something and press enter, then it will continue to execute and if that's the case output something.